# I can't seem to see what's missing in my JavaScript and HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and am having a difficult time having my computations displayed. The message on my JavaScript code said that it was missing a declaration variable. I really don't know what else to try since I'm new to this and I've been stuck on this for a few days now, it's extremely embarrassing. Here is my HTML code where the computations should display and the corresponding JavaScript to it:

```
function compute() {
    var principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("principal").value);
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementByIdementById("rate").value);
    var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("years").value);
    var result = principal * years * rate /100;
    var years = new Date().getFullYear()+parseInt(years);
}

<button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
<span id="result"></span>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function compute() {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "If you deposit<mark>"
   +principal+"</mark>,<br/> at an interest rate of<mark>"
   +rate+"%</mark><br/>. You will receive an amount of<mark>"+result+
   ",</mark><br/>in the year<mark>"+year+"</mark><br/>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello! Take a closer look at the errors you are getting, what are they saying exactly? You also have two functions with the same name `compute`, which is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome on StackOverflow.

Let's go to watch your code, there are several errors:

1. You have declared a function `compute()` (the first one) that create and assign a value to some variables whose scope is inside the function!
   In the second `compute()` function you are trying to access the value of those variables that are not declared inside it and whose scope is limited to the first function -> so the compiler will give the error `Undefined variable`.
2. There is a misspell of `getElementById`:
   `var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementByIdementById("rate").value);`
3. In the first `compute()` function you have declared a variable using the same name `years` -> better to use a different name or simply overwrite it.
4. You have used the same `id="result"` in two different HTML tags, that does not have sense because `id` should identify only one element; I suppose that you want to put the result of the elaboration inside the `<p>` element.

So you have to do modify your code and put it inside one `compute()` function:

```
<script>
function compute() {
    var principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("principal").value);
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate").value);
    var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("years").value);
    var result = principal * years * rate /100;
    var years_modified = new Date().getFullYear() + parseInt(years);

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "If you deposit<mark>"
   + principal + "</mark> , <br/> at an interest rate of<mark>"
   + rate + "%</mark><br/>. You will receive an amount of<mark>" + result +
   ",</mark><br/>in the year<mark>" + years_modified + "</mark><br/>";
}
</script>

<button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
<span></span>
<p id="result"></p>
```

- Reference: [Scope of JavaScript functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

P.S = I would like to give you a suggestion, avoid using the same name for more than one function, you may run into unexpected behavior

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew there was a declaration problem; I was thinking about it all night long. I tried it and it worked. Thank you so much for the response and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Nomnomers No problem, if you find my answer useful and it has solved your issue consider to Accept it as answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

HTML:

```
<script>
function compute() 
  {
   var principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("principal").value);
   var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate").value);
   var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("years").value);
   var result = principal * years * rate /100;
   var years_result = new Date().getFullYear()+parseInt(years);
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "If you deposit<mark>"
   +principal+"</mark>,<br/> at an interest rate of<mark>"
   +rate+"%</mark><br/>. You will receive an amount of<mark>"+result+
   ",</mark><br/>in the year<mark>"+years_result+"</mark><br/>";
   }
 </script>
<button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
<span id="result"></span>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you! I've checked this, as well, and it worked. I'm honestly just embarrassed that my issue was so easily rectified. Thank you for your response and your time and sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @Nomnomers Dont't worry! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is will work.

```
function compute() {
  var principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("principal").value);
  var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate").value);
  var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("years").value);
  var result = principal * years * rate / 100;
  var years_result = new Date().getFullYear() + parseInt(years);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `
    If you deposit <mark>${principal}</mark>
    <br/> at an interest rate of
    <mark>${rate}%</mark><br/>.
    You will receive an amount of <mark>${result}</mark>
    <br/> in the year <mark>${years_result}</mark><br/>`;
}
```

You also had an error on `var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementByIdementById("rate").value);`

And when specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it and it worked. I didn't know there were other ways to specify HTML elements; thank you for informing me. Thank you for the response and your time.